# Authentication between Azure Web PubSub and server

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-pubsub

There is a simple ASP.NET app as an event handler Server:

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services
    .AddWebPubSub(options => options.ServiceEndpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(WebPubSubConnectionString))
    .AddWebPubSubServiceClient<WebPubSubHub>();

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

app.MapWebPubSubHub<WebPubSubHub>("/eventhandler");
app.Run();
```

The Azure Web PubSub has the following configuration of Webhook URL:

[image]

I need to protect this endpoint somehow `/eventhandler` because it's public and anyone can call it. One of the options that Azure suggests is using a simple authentication code.
[image]

Help me to understand where I should verify that code in my ASP.NET app?

Let's say I configured the URL template in WPS like

```
https://a9e5-92-253-212-316.ngrok-free.app/eventhandler?code=RRRRR
```

then in the server code

```
app.MapWebPubSubHub<WebPubSubHub>("/eventhandler?code=RRRRR")
```

result is exception

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Patterns.RoutePatternException: 'The
> literal section 'eventhandler?code=RRRRR' is invalid. Literal sections
> cannot contain the '?' character.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to use `AddEndpointFilter`

```
app.MapWebPubSubHub<WebPubSubHub>("/eventhandler").AddEndpointFilter(new ApiKeyFilter(builder.Configuration));
```

the implementation could look like this:

```
public class ApiKeyFilter : IEndpointFilter
{
    private readonly string _apiKey;

    public ApiKeyFilter(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _apiKey = configuration.GetValue<string>("ApiKey");
    }

    public async ValueTask<object> InvokeAsync(EndpointFilterInvocationContext context, EndpointFilterDelegate next)
    {
        if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Query.TryGetValue("code", out var extractedApiKey))
        {
            return Results.Unauthorized();
        }

        if (!_apiKey.Equals(extractedApiKey))
        {
            return Results.Unauthorized();
        }

        return await next(context);
    }
}
```

another option is to use

```
app.MapWebPubSubHub<WebPubSubHub>`("/eventhandler").RequireAuthorization(builder => builder.AddRequirements(new ApiKeyRequirement))
```

where `ApiKeyRequirement` is your implementation of `IAuthorizationRequirement`